# Remove php extension from htaccess but keep PATH_INFO functional

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I make URLs like http://localhost/index.php/add/

The /add/ after the index.php is $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and can be used in PHP coding.

I want to remove the .php from this URL using .htaccess and still keep using the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], no matter how may segments there are.

For instance,

```
http://localhost/index.php/add/cars/
http://localhost/index.php/add/cars/japan/
http://localhost/index.php/add/cars/japan/tokyo/
```

I also want a trailing slash at the end as in the examples above.

I can remove the .php extension using the script below, but I need a bit more than that.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That rule will rewrite `index.php/add/cars/` to `index.php/add/cars/.php`, no? Just use `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`. It's really that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index(/.+)?$ index.php$1 [NC,L]
```

If you also use another name (and not always `index`). Change the last line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)(/.+)?$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect, but in addition to this, I also want. localhost/index.php to show as localhost/index/ - please note, there is a slash at the end on index.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```